# R: Calculate correlation for a subset of my dataset?

Tags: r, correlation

I have a dataset with 20 variables v1 - v20. Now I'd like to use cor(...) to calculate the correlation between v2 and v10 until v15 and v3 and v10 until v15. What's the best way to do this? Do I have to do this for each variable pair using

```
cor(v2, v10)
cor(v2, v11)
cor(v2, v12)
and so on?
```

Here is the actual dataset:

```
   > dput(dataset)
structure(list(Number = 1:15, Question.1.1 = c(3L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 
4L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L), Question.1.2 = c(1L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), Question.2.1 = c(5L, 
3L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L), Question.2.2 = c(2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), Question.3.1 = c(2L, 
NA, 4L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 4L), Question.3.2 = c(2L, 
NA, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L), Question.4.1 = c(3L, 
2L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 2L), Question.4.2 = c(2L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L), Question.5.1 = c(5L, 
3L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L), Question.5.2 = c(2L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), Question.6.1 = c(5L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 1L), Question.6.2 = c(2L, 
3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L), Question.7.1 = c(5L, 
2L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L), Question.7.2 = c(1L, 
4L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), Question.8.1 = c(4L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L), Question.8.2 = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), Question.9.1 = c(5L, 
3L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 3L), Question.9.2 = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L), AQ.1 = c(5L, 
5L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 3L), AQ.2 = c(2L, 
5L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 3L), Task.1 = c(5L, 
2L, 5L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L), Task.2 = c(4L, 
3L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L), Task.3 = c(4L, 
3L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 4L), Task.4 = c(5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L), Task.5 = c(5L, 
4L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L), GQ.1 = c(4L, 
2L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 4L), GQ.2 = c(4L, 
4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 3L), GQ.3 = c(5L, 
3L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 4L), GQ.4 = c(5L, 
2L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 1L), GQ.5 = c(4L, 
3L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 3L), GQ.6 = c(2L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 5L), GQ.7 = c(4L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 2L), GQ.8 = c(2L, 
4L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L), GQ.9 = c(3L, 
5L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 2L), GQ.10 = c(3L, 
4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 2L), Feature.1 = c(4L, 
4L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 4L), Feature.2 = c(4L, 
4L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 2L), Feature.3 = c(3L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 2L), Feature.4 = c(3L, 
3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L), Feature.5 = c(2L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 1L), Feature.6 = c(5L, 
5L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L), Feature.7 = c(5L, 
3L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L)), .Names = c("Number", 
"Question.1.1", "Question.1.2", "Question.2.1", "Question.2.2", 
"Question.3.1", "Question.3.2", "Question.4.1", "Question.4.2", 
"Question.5.1", "Question.5.2", "Question.6.1", "Question.6.2", 
"Question.7.1", "Question.7.2", "Question.8.1", "Question.8.2", 
"Question.9.1", "Question.9.2", "AQ.1", "AQ.2", "Task.1", "Task.2", 
"Task.3", "Task.4", "Task.5", "GQ.1", "GQ.2", "GQ.3", "GQ.4", 
"GQ.5", "GQ.6", "GQ.7", "GQ.8", "GQ.9", "GQ.10", "Feature.1", 
"Feature.2", "Feature.3", "Feature.4", "Feature.5", "Feature.6", 
"Feature.7"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -15L))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I may have misunderstood the problem... but why don't you just to run `cor` on the data frame?

For instance:

```
data <- data.frame(q1=sample(1:5, 15, rep=1), 
          q2=sample(1:5, 15, rep=1), 
          q3=sample(1:5, 15, rep=1), 
          q4=sample(1:5, 15, rep=1), 
          q5=sample(1:5, 15, rep=1), 
          q6=sample(1:5, 15, rep=1), 
          q7=sample(1:5, 15, rep=1), 
          q8=sample(1:5, 15, rep=1), 
          q9=sample(1:5, 15, rep=1), 
          q10=sample(1:5, 15, rep=1))

print(cor(data))
```

You can even

```
image(cor(data), x=1:10, y=1:10, zlim=c(-1,1))
```

If you just need certain values of correlations just put the result of corr in a variable and pull out the results you need.

For instance, we want the correlation of column 2 with columns 5 to 10 we will:

```
corrs <- cor(data)
print(corrs[2, 5:10]) # or corrs[5:10, 2], the correlation matrix is symmetric
```

Comment: Ok thanks. I have to check the commands, I'm really new to R. The problem was if I just use cor(dataset) there are way to much correlations calculated.

Comment: Thanks. print(cor(data)) is working but if I dtry to display it as an image, I dont see any values on the image..

Comment: I updated the answer to show how to get only specific correlation values.

Comment: Try removing the x and y parameters from the `image` call, then it should work with your data too.

Comment: Thanks this seems to work. Now I have another problem... I used  print(corrs[2:19, 20:21]) and got the results I expected... but 6 cells contain the value NA... What are the reasons that there isn't a value available?

Comment: @nico:Ok I saw it myself. The problem is that this variable has no variation. That is, it has always the value 2...

Comment: Exactly, in fact you will see a warning when you call `cor`, saying "the standard deviation is 0". See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3798998/cor-shows-only-na-or-1-for-correlations-why

Comment: @nico: Yes I already found that when googeling ;) Do you also know a link that explains the statistical background why I can't calculate a correlation when the standard deviation is 0?

Comment: @Roflcoptr: as the correlation coefficient is computed by dividing by the standard deviations, see e.g. on Wikipedia (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlation_and_dependence)

Answer (score 1):

Subset the dataset explicitly and run the correlation command on that dataset. Assuming your variables are ordered properly, try something like this:

```
cor(dat[,c(2, 10:15)][,1]
cor(dat[,c(3, 10:15)][,1]
```

If they are not ordered, you'll just need to order them or name the variables in quotes instead. E.g.:

```
cor(dat[,c('v3', 'v10', 'v11', 'v12', 'v13', 'v14', 'v15')][,1]
```

Comment: I tried this but then I get an error. Unfortunately it is in german:  Objekt des Typs 'closure' ist nicht indizierbar

Comment: Can you give us a chunk of the actual dataset. Subset it (cut out rows), and paste the output of dput(dat)

Comment: You have missing data in there. Read ?cor to find an option that handles missing values (e.g. All observations, or case wise). Also, make sure that all your variables are of a good type (e.g. Numeric or integer). Pasting your dataset is also much less useful than pasting the dput() result since th e

Comment: I have one missing value. Ok i changed the question again and used dput()

Answer (score 1):

Use `subset` command:

```
dtf <- subset(mtcars, select = c(mpg, hp, wt))
cor(dtf)
         mpg         hp         wt
mpg  1.0000000 -0.7761684 -0.8676594
hp  -0.7761684  1.0000000  0.6587479
wt  -0.8676594  0.6587479  1.0000000
```

Or use `psych` package and `corr.test` function:

```
library(psych)
corr.test(dtf)
Call:corr.test(x = dtf)
Correlation matrix 
      mpg    hp    wt
mpg  1.00 -0.78 -0.87
hp  -0.78  1.00  0.66
wt  -0.87  0.66  1.00
Sample Size 
    mpg hp wt
mpg  32 32 32
hp   32 32 32
wt   32 32 32
Probability value 
    mpg hp wt
mpg   0  0  0
hp    0  0  0
wt    0  0  0
```

Answer (score 1):

The question seems  motivated by the information overload that results from running corr on the entire dataframe.  I have not used it much but the [plyr package](http://plyr.had.co.nz/) by Hadley Wickham of ggplot fame seems to offer some elegant solutions to subsetting and managing the output.